# How to make HTTP request async/await in Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions, axios

I'm trying to make a JSON call with async/await using Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Any idea how to fix the following code? My plan is Blaze.

My inspiration is https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-requests-node-js-async-await/

**DEPLOY ERROR**

> functions[setDetails]: Deployment error.
>
> const getDetails = async url => {
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>       at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at getUserFunction (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:378:24)

**INDEX.JS**

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');    
// Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js
const axios = require('axios');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const url = 'https://api.xxxx.com/json?partnumber=';
const getDetails = async url => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const data = response.data;
        const getDet = data.results[0].details;
        return getDet;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
};
exports.setDetails = functions.database.ref('/equipment/{pushId}').onWrite((event) => {
  const post = event.data.val();
  if (post.details){ return };
  const number = post.number;
  const details = getDetails(url + number);
  admin.database().ref('/equipment/{pushId}').push({number: number, details: details});
});
```

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "look-at-details",
  "description": "bla bla bla",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.9.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1"
  },  
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  }
}
```

Comment: what line is the error?

Comment: @PeterHaddad line 9 till line 19.

Comment: @PeterHaddad In line 13 I tried to use ${data.results[0].details}. the same error happens

Comment: `Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. /home/MyID/MyFolder/functions/index.js:19 });`

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the entire output from the deploy rather than just the one error log line?

Answer (score 1):

async/await is not yet supported natively by Cloud Functions.  Cloud Functions runs node 6, which doesn't use a version of JavaScript that supports async/await.  The deploy is failing because it doesn't know the `async` keyword.

Instead, you could initialize your project to use TypeScript, which supports async/await.  The Firebase CLI will automatically transpile your code to ES6 that uses Promises to implement async/await.

Comment: GCF now supports async/await, which you already know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is rather than using `async wait` you could use another library called [`request-promise-any`](https://github.com/request/request-promise-any)